# How to make property that is alias to model.attr when model set, otherwise to default.attr?

Tags: binding, ember.js

How can I make a (two-way) property that is an alias to `model.someProperty` if model is not empty, and otherwise is an alias to `default.someProperty`? Currently I wrap two versions of a `<select>` in an `{{#if model}}`, one bound to model and one bound to defaults, but I would like to remove the logic from the template. Also there are certain circumstances where the set fires before the `select` gets swapped, leading to an error because model is null.

When setting model, the new model should get `someProperty` set to `default.someProperty`. Currently I do that by:

```
modelChanged: function(){
  if(default && default.get('someProperty')){
    this.set('model.someProperty', default.get('someProperty'));
  }
}.observes('model')
```

and I'm also curious to know if this is the *Best* way to do that.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, using few lines. I made a computed macro for this in that fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/3LD6a/. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

`DS.attr()` can take [a default value](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/attributes.js#L95). Does that help?

```
var Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string', { defaultValue: "Work in progress" })
```

Comment: The default needs to be dynamic. But @marcio-rodrigues-correa-junior's fiddle shows a way to do it that works better than my first try, which was everything in a computed property. I have to check whether doing it his way suffers from what my way did: the computed property gets fired twice.

Comment: defaultValue can also take a function, if that helps. By sticking with DS.attr you already get an Ember.computed property that deals with the getter and setter. Anyways, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible, using few lines. But, it's possible to create a computed property macro:

```
var get = Ember.get, set = Ember.set;

Ember.computed.aliasWithDefaultTo = function(dependentKey, defaultPath) {
  return Ember.computed(dependentKey, defaultPath, function(key, value) {
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      set(this, dependentKey, value || get(this, defaultPath));
      return value;
    } else {
      return get(this, dependentKey) || get(this, defaultPath);
    }
  });
};
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/3LD6a/